# Simultaneous Python and C++ run with read and write files

Tags: python, c++

So this one is a doozie, and a little too specific to find an answer online.

I am writing to a file in C++ and reading that file in Python at the same time to move a robot. Or trying to.

When I try running both programs at the same time, the C++ one runs first and then the Python one runs.

Here's the command I use:

`./ColorFollow & python fileToHex.py`

This happens even if I switch the order of commands.
Even if I run them in different terminals (which is the same thing, just covering all bases).

Both the Python and C++ code read / write in 'infinite' loops, so these two should run until I say stop.

The code works fine; when the Python script finally runs the robot moves as intended. It's just that the code doesn't run at the same time.

Is there a way to make this happen, or is this impossible?

If you need more information, lemme know, but the code is pretty much what you'd expect it to be.

Comment: By using `&`, you release bash session and get only Python script output. So, I suggest to make a service file with stop flag. Or stop one process from other.

Comment: Instead of a file, consider using a pipe.

Comment: Did you mean to run `./ColorFollow | python fileToHex.py`?

Comment: @ETech - If this is a unixy system, `ColorFollow`'s `stdin` is detached from the session but can be reattached with `fg`. Its `stdout` and `stderr` will continue writing to the terminal screen.

Comment: @Jean - something else must be going on. They should run in parallel. Maybe there is some odd interaction between these scripts and their shared files?

Comment: [Doozer](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/muppet/images/4/4e/FraggleRock-DoozerPortrait03.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20101120181421)

Comment: I mean - use a kind of flag somewhere. That is being read by both loops and appended with 1, for instance upon exit of each app. What you wrote - you redirect ColorFollow output to fileToHex stdin.

Comment: How about writing a simple example using python on both sides that we can test?

Comment: "these two should run until I say stop" ... how do you do that? `ColorFollow` will hang reading its `stdin` because its in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, `&` will release bash session and in this case, CollorFlow and fileToXex.py will run in different bash sessions.
At the same time, composition `./ColorFollow | python fileToHex.py` looks interesting, cause you redirect stdout of ColorFollow to fileToHex.py stdin - it can syncronize scripts by printing some code string upon exit, then reading it by fileToHex.py and exit as well.
I would create some empty file like `/var/run/ColorFollow.flag` and write there 1 when one of processes exit. Not a pipe - cause we do not care which process will start first. So, if next loop step of ColorFollow sees 1 in the file, it deletes it and exits (means that fileToHex already exited). The same - for fileToHex - check flag file each loop step and exit if it exists, after deleting flag file.